# Make menu sublinks appear when hovering over the link

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

My site is londontradition.com I am trying to get the menu links 'about us' and 'journal' to show the sublinks when a mouse is hovered above. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code for the part of the menu I need this effect to work on.

```
<li id="menu-item-749" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub open"><a href="#"><span>About us</span>
</a><ul style="display: block;">
<li id="menu-item-1006" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.londontradition.com/about-us/history/"><span>HISTORY</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1007" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.londontradition.com/about-us/heritage/"><span>HERITAGE</span></a></li></ul><span class="holder"></span></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to hide you children menu by `display:none`. After that you can trigger the parent menu using `:hover` in CSS and `display:block` for the child menu there. This should open the submenu by hovering.

Here is an example:

```css
.menu-children {
  display: none;
}
.menu-item-has-children:hover .menu-children {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-749" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub open"><a href="#"><span>About us</span>
</a>
  <ul class="menu-children">
    <li id="menu-item-1006" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.londontradition.com/about-us/history/"><span>HISTORY</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1007" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.londontradition.com/about-us/heritage/"><span>HERITAGE</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul><span class="holder"></span>
</li>
```

Please notice to give your child menu `ul` list the class `menu-children` (as example in this code snippet)

**Update**

I noticed your page is using a JavaScript, which sets the `display` parameter. That's why you need to change your JavaScript **or** you can try the following CSS:

```
.menu-children {
  display: none !important;
}
.menu-item-has-children:hover .menu-children {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Look at the `!important` tags for the `display` parameters in the CSS.

Comment: Hi I have tried implementing this on my website but it made no changes.

Comment: @KumarPatel I just had a look on your page and think JavaScript is handling your menu open/close mechanism. Maybe you can provide some more details about the theme/template?

Comment: @KumarPatel Also please check my updated answer. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css.

Try somthing like this:

```
.parent:hover {
  .child {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: <li id="menu-item-749" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub open"><a href="#"><span>About us</span></a><ul style="display: block;"><li id="menu-item-1006" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.londontradition.com/about-us/history/"><span>HISTORY</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-1007" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://www.londontradition.com/about-us/heritage/"><span>HERITAGE</span></a></li></ul><span class="holder"></span></li>

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, css and javascript. I find the easiest way is with CSS.

```
.subMenu {display:none;}
.menuItem:hover .subMenu{ display:block;}
```

Comment: I have put this in my CSS but it did not work

.menu-item-1006 {display:none;}
..menu-item-749:hover .menu-item-1006{ display:block;}

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, ok nobody has looked at the page...

It is simply a ***selector-thing*** in your code is this selector written to hide all submenus.

```
#mobile-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    ...
}
```

So you have to write an selector like this with an higher priority to show the submenu on hover.

```
#mobile-menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

You can read an article about selector-priorty here: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

---

But now you got another problem, you have an Javascript function that show and hide the submenu and this collides with the `:hover`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.holder', function() {
   ... do hide and show things ...
});
```

So you have to add an ugly !important to your code that overwrites the inline style from the Javascript function on hover (`style="display:none;`):

```
#mobile-menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block !important;
}
```

A better way would be to edit the function and add a new **leave** function too:

```
$('body').on('click mouseenter', '.holder', function() {
   ... do show (and hide on click) thing ...
});
```

and

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.has-sub', function() {
   ... do hide thing ...
});
```

The second function is on the complete `<li class="... has-sub ...">` with submenu to get a chance to klick the submenu ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Do you know where I can find the file containing the javascript code?

Comment: It could be in the **template.js** file. Best way: search in your project folder for the string **'.holder'**